# Cable gland with thicker rubber seal/apron

Tags: wiring, waterproofing, data-wiring, connectors

I'm looking to use a cable gland to waterproof a low voltage valve actuator connection in a junction box. I have a cable gland appropriately sized for the wire, however the connector on the end of the wire is too large to fit through the gland opening. Using a larger gland fits the connector, but does not create a tight seal around the wire sheathing.

[image: Normal cable gland seal]

I have seen similar gland in an outdoor ethernet splice which contains a female/female connector with a a normal cable gland on each side. However, these include a larger rubber seal with a cut on the side allowing it to be placed around the ethernet cable from the side, and is thicker to accommodate the wider gland opening.

[image: Ethernet connector gland]

Where can I find this type of rubber seal (blue in the photo above) or a cable gland that includes them? I don't want to buy a bunch of ethernet splices that I don't need.

Comment: If it's just an Ethernet cable, remove the connector, pass the cable into the j-box, then crimp a new connector onto the cable.  That's how the seal you already have is intended to be used.  Putting a connector on an Ethernet cable is fairly easy and as long as you don't need to certify it (requires an expensive tool) the crimper is inexpensive.

Comment: @Jeff Wheeler That would work for an Ethernet cable (I have a crimper and terminals), but this is a JST 3-pin connector and I would prefer to leave the cable untouched. The Ethernet splice/gland is large enough to fit a terminated cable and the rubber seal is thick enough to seal tightly (I actually had one of these laying around).

Comment: Maybe it'd be better posed as "How do I make a weatherproof entry to a box with XYZ spec cable?"

Comment: If you have a gland the right size, then make a cut with a knife and place it over the wire. Snug up the nut as usual. The cut will seal rubber to rubber, no different from any other portion where the rubber presses against the connector body.

Comment: @John Canon That’s how the blue rubber seal works in the photo with the network splice; I’m looking for a place to purchase just that thicker rubber seal (or a gland that comes with thicker seals)

Comment: I see it now. I have used these connectors for outdoor security camera installations. To build up the wire thickness, wrap a few turns of duct tape around the wire.

Comment: "[I’m looking for a place to purchase](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/204845/cable-gland-with-thicker-rubber-seal-apron#comment373021_204845)" makes this an off-topic shopping question